# function won't take the global value as an argument and reset it?

Tags: javascript, function, countdown

I wanna make a function that decreases the `counter` everytime it gets called, sorta like a `countDown` function, but every time the `counter` hits `0` I wanna reset it to `20`. However since I'm gonna apply that function on multiple variables, I've decided to make a `reset` function that takes the `variable` that I wanna countdown as an argument , and everytime that `variable` hits 0 it'll reset it to `20`. but somehow it won't work!

```js
    let counter = 20;

    function countDown() {
      console.log(counter);
   
      counter--;
      
      // reset counter to 20 when counter < 0
      reset(counter);
      
      setTimeout( () => {
        countDown()
      }, 250 )
    }
    
    // function to reset counter to 20 when counter < 0
    function reset(number) {
      if ( number < 0 ) {
        number = 20;
      }
    };

    countDown();
```

Comment: `reset()` and `function reset() { if(counter < 0) { counter = 20} }`

Comment: I wanna be able to use the same function on another variable without hardcoding `if (counter < 0) { counter = 0}`. I wanted the function to work on whatever variable that takes it as an argument.

Comment: Your `number` variable is a copy of the `counter` value you're passing into`reset()`,  so changing `number` won't update `counter`, as you're modifying the copy and not the original global counter variable. If you want to make your function generic, you can `return` the new value you want to assign to counter from `reset()`, and then update counter in your countDown() function: `counter = reset(counter)`

Comment: @Nick I see, so in this case I have to add logic everytime I wanna `countDown` a new variable. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When you are passing `counter` to the `reset function` you are passing the value of `counter` and not the actual reference to `counter`. So you cannot actually change the counter using reset unless you are accessing it directly.

As you want to do some similar resets to other variables in the future, You can try a similar approach like this

```js
const store = {
  counter: 5
};


function reset(propertyName, resetTo) {
  if (store[propertyName] < 0) {
    store[propertyName] = resetTo;

    console.log(`${propertyName} has been reset to ${resetTo}`);
  }
}

function countDown() {
  console.log(store.counter);

  store.counter--;

  // reset counter to 5 when counter < 0
  reset("counter", 5);

  setTimeout(() => {
    countDown()
  }, 1000)
}

countDown()
```

Comment: Thank you , I like the solution you came up with